# Intellij - work-around for IDE not building module on Run/Debug

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, cucumber

I have a pretty large project, of which the Selenium/Cucumber part is integrated, and belongs to me.

No, after upgrading to Intelij 2022, I find that things have changed to the worse. Since I only bother about the module containin cucumber/selenium tests, I have been used to just clicking Run or Debug on each Run/Debug configuration to get my changes built, and the Cucumber/Selenium tests run locally on my computer.

This doesn't work anymore, and absolutely 100% of all help/support I have found on the net is unhelpful. The problem is that when I make a change in the code and click Run or Debug, the module (cucumber, where all the Cucumber/selenium tests resides) is not built. So, it keeps running the previously built code when I'm working on debugging/fixing tests.

The solution has been to first build the module containing the tests, then run/debug the test(s). Even though the run/debug configuration DOES have "Build" before launch. But this is tiresome, and a total waste of time.

So, what I'm wondering is: Can I tailer a terminal command to do all this? That is, build a specified module, then Run or Debug a Cucumber test.

Any help/hints are appreciated. I'm experiencting the usual "me" problem, where it seems that everyone else in the world has something working, while the same solutions doesn't work for me.

EDIT:
I tried the solution offered below in the comments: Deleted the .idea folder, reimported all Maven modules and reconfigured the project. It seemed to work on the first run, but then it went back to not building before launch.

Comment: I had a similar "me" problem after upgrading IntelliJ. No unit tests were working by IDE. Warnings / errors were everywhere. Of course no problem at all with gradle build / test. The solution for me was deleting .idea folder.

Comment: There is a `.idea` folder under your project directory. It is hidden in unix type systems.

Comment: Unfortunately, the way IntelliJ works, if I do that my whole projects is ruined. IntelliJ stops recognizing all of the cucumeber step definitions, and there is no solution for that. It's just luck when it actually works.

Comment: Try these steps. 1. Close your project. 2. Copy all project files. 3. Remove .idea folder from the newly copied project. 4. Open the new project. 5. Intellij should reindex all your new project.

Comment: I did, and I got the project up an running again. However, it only took ONE run before things were back to not working. Man, I'm getting REALLY tired of this IntellliJ c**p now. It's nothing but trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change Select Run/Debug configuration in idea. Change Build to Build Project. It worked for me.

[image: here you can find changes]

[image: change build to build project here]